# How to display the same products in new store / website

Tags: magento-1.8, store-view, websites, stores

I already have a website/store with more products. I need to show the same products in new store/website. my old website url is localhost. and my new website/store url is localhost/store1. But if i click any category or product, it is loading like localhost/store1/category-name.html. But showing 404 error and showing old store design. But Home page is working fine.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1 :** Login to Admin and navigate to `Catalog->Manage Products` , Now all your products will list here.

**Step-2 :** Press Check All on left corner of the table view or select any single or  multiple records from the table list

**Step-3 :** Now, you can find drop down with the label Actions on the right corner of the table list, in the drop down list, you can find Delete, Change Status and Update Attributes.

**Step-4 :** For Attributes to be update, Select the option `Update Attributes` and press Submit button. Now, a new window will open with the fields Name, Description, Inventory, Websites ….etc, you need to update the fields which you want to update.

**Step-5 :** Now, open Websites tab and click checkbox for each websites to add Product To Websites also Remove Product From Websites

**Step-6 :** Click on the Change checkbox below each field to update, and enter values on corresponding fields and press Save , you are done.

Comment: If i choose the websites, the products are displaying in Home page, but if i click the category or a product. it is redirecting to 404 page and old store design.

Comment: have you create categories both store same or difference?

Comment: I did not create separate category for new store. I need to use the same category.